# How can I test that an object is created with the right constructor parameters from a factory in PHP?

Tags: php, phpunit

I want to test that the API is created correctly from the factory below. The API does not have any getters nor public properties for any of the constructor parameters passed, however the correctness is already tested in the test for the API itself. I just want to test the factory that it passes the correct constructor parameters to the API.

The requirement is the following:

- I want to verify that the API is constructed with the `$client` injected into the constructor, along with the `$language`, `$appid` and `$syscode5` passed into the method if they are specified.
- If either of `$appid` and `$syscode5` is not provided, it calls another public method of the class `getSecret()` which will attempt to get the values. This method is stubbed when testing the factory. I want to verify that the factory passes the values from the method in the constructor `$appid` and `$syscode5` parameters when constructing the API.

```php
class ApiFactory {
    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function __invoke(int $language = Api::TRADITIONAL_CHINESE, ?string $appid = NULL, ?string $syscode5 = NULL) {
        $secret = NULL;
        if ($appid === NULL || $syscode5 === NULL) {
            $secret = $this->getSecret();
        }
        return new Api($this->client, $appid ?? $secret->appid, $syscode5 ?? $secret->syscode5, $language);
    }

    public function getSecret() : stdClass {
        // omitted
    }

    /**
     * @var ClientInterface
     */
    private $client;
}
```

I can't think of a way to verify that the constructor is called with the correct values. The nearest thing I can do is refactor out the actual construction a new protected method called `makeApi` with the exact same signature with the constructor in the IUT and mock it in the unit tests.

```php
    public function __invoke(int $language = Api::TRADITIONAL_CHINESE, ?string $appid = NULL, ?string $syscode5 = NULL) {
        $secret = NULL;
        if ($appid === NULL || $syscode5 === NULL) {
            $secret = $this->getSecret();
        }
        return $this->makeApi($this->client, $appid ?? $secret->appid, $syscode5 ?? $secret->syscode5, $language);
    }

    protected function makeApi(
        ClientInterface $client
        , string $appid
        , string $syscode5
        , int $language = Api::TRADITIONAL_CHINESE
        , ?string $baseUrl = NULL
    ) : Api {
        return new Api($client, $appid, $syscode5, $language, $baseUrl);
    }
```

However, the new protected method remains untestable. If it is replaced with some other return values such as `new Api(new Client(), '', '', 5, 'http://example.com')` the test still won't fail.

How can I properly test this piece of code?

Comment: As far as I know, Mock, Spy, ... Will not provide you with the constructor expectation, and of course, it's not logical. I would say if the API class has the right signature for the arguments you are passing. Then I guess there is nothing to worry about it. What you can do is to write the appropriate tests for API class, so in case of appid was null your code should return for example A otherwise B.

Comment: The appid can't be null for the API - it's the job of the factory to provide a suitable value to create the API.

Comment: Mmm, Well the second implementation is better I guess. The problem with private and protected methods is that we can't write a test for them, But we can check for their side-effect, I would suggest, Write the appropriate tests for the __invoke and expect the results base on the request you are passing. I don't know what new API is returning for you. But if it's returning the created object then you can check it against your expectation.

Comment: It is possible to test for protected methods - the problem is that I don't know how I can test the call to `new`.

Comment: As I said, There is no way, You can expect a specific return from makeApi method base on the parameters you are passing.

Comment: Have you considered using reflection? I wouldn't recommend using it generally in production code, but for some test cases I sometimes uses a helper method (maybe in a trait) to extract a private property